# ThreadMonitor WSDR06W: Thread "server.startup : 2" (000000c0) has been active for 804,563 milliseconds and may be hung

Tags: websphere-7

I am geting below exception while starting server(Websphere)

ThreadMonitor WSD5566W: Thread "server.startup : 2" (000000c0) has been active for 804,563 milliseconds and may be hung.

I have increase thread pool size from 10 to 100 but still have issue.

Comment: Poolsize has nothing to do with it. You just have something which is either very slow or hangs during startup. Check the log what is going on, you may try to create thread dump (kill -3) and see what threads are doing.

Comment: The thread monitor message should have included a stack trace, and you should include that stack trace here if you want more help.

Comment: is it any heap space issue?